# Redirect to referrer not working after Login

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.4

After logging a user in, I want to redirect them back to where they came from but It's not working properly in CakePHP 3.5. Here are the required info's to help me figure out this problem.

URL while login(session time out),

```
http://dev.scys.com/db/admin?redirect=%2Fadmin%2Fstatuses
```

This is my Auth config,

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'loginAction' => ['controller' => 'Admins', 'action' => 'login'],
            'loginRedirect' => ['controller' => 'Admins', 'action' => 'index'],
            'logoutRedirect' => ['controller' => 'Admins', 'action' => 'login'],
            'unauthorizedRedirect' => $this->referer(),
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'finder' => 'auth',
                    'userModel' => 'Admins',
                    'fields' => ['username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password']
                ]
            ]

        ]);
```

And in the Login method/action

```
$user = $this->Auth->identify();
            if ($user) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
```

> More Points
>
> I have also tried $this->redirect($this->request->getQuery('redirect'));

Am I missing anything or something else I have to add to work this out :(

Comment: Try  `Router::url( $this->referer(), true ) `

Comment: This is now working for me :(

Comment: Did you mean now working or not working? Did you put it into `$this->redirect(Router::url( $this->referer(), true )`?

Comment: Mistyped, not working, yes I did the same

Comment: Where is the user currently being redirected to? What is actually happening with your current code?

Comment: Figured out my mistake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my mistake,
Actually, I was using for action URL like,

```
$this->Form->create(NULL, ['url'=> ['controller' => 'Admins', 'action' => 'login'],'style'=>'display: block;');
```

Because of this, the URL became "admins/login" and the redirect query string get removed that's why the problem occurred, because "`$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());`" didn't find any redirect query string(as per the case 1), so it uses `$this->Auth->config('loginRedirect');`(as per case 2).

Then I solve it by removing the URL key and value from the **form create option parameter**.